# AutoCompleteMode not working textbox C#

Tags: c#-4.0

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            AutoCompleteStringCollection nc = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        nc.AddRange(new string[]
        {
            "boston",
            "sanfransisco"
        });
        textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = nc;
        textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;


    }
```

Autocomplete isn't working and I don't know why. If I add more strings to the array they still don't show up and I've tried moving new AutoCompleteStringCollection() out of the private method. I have the properties set the same way in the form properties too.

Do you have to import something for AutoCompleteMode to work?

Comment: Can you confirm with the debugger that this code is executed?

Comment: Yes the code is executed

Comment: I have tried the same code and works as expected. Do you have any non default property set for the textbox?

Comment: It is multiline, and has the vertical scrollbar. It is also docked

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on [AutoCompleteSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletesource%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) you can find this note

> AutoCompleteSource does not work on multiline TextBox controls.

So you could only switch to a MultiLine=false to have your code to work.

Searching on the NET there are [various solutions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/02177ccb-befc-4bf3-9580-a5439c9d48ba/autocomplete-on-multiline-textbox) that give to a multiline textbox the functionality of AutoComplete, but they always include some tweaking on the PreviewKeyDown method